# Best practice for sending data between groovy and powershell processes?

Tags: json, powershell, groovy

I'm currently working on a project that has front-end components (Jira) written in groovy, and backend processes written in powershell. We're using json to pass information back and forth. One of the biggest problems we've encountered is coming up with a standardized "template" for the json that is being used on both ends. What we have works, but it is a frankenstein mess.

We are using json libraries for both json and powershell -- the json that is being constructed on either end is legit json. We are also encoding it to base64 to get around interpolation issues we've run into.

My main question is this: what is the best practice for passing data between different tools in json? I'm relatively new to it. Is there some sort of standard template we should be adhering to? I develop the groovy side, my friend the powershell side -- I was hoping to come up with something that would minimize problems if someone messed up how the json was constructed on either side. Something to check against. Something akin to an xsd.

Was curious if people have dealt with this type of thing, and what the best approach was. As I mentioned before, we have something that works now -- with error handling and whatnot, but it was very organic... and not standardized at all. I saw mention of jasonp, jsend, etc., but having some difficulty groking the options.

Tips/guidance appreciated.

Comment: Can you talk to each other and work on a shared document description? Talking to each other, and agreeing a json format should remove the need for a schema

Comment: What about something like [JSON.net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonSchema.htm) which you can call from PowerShell?

Comment: IMHO if you need a json schema, you're doing it wrong

Comment: Hi Tim, that is entirely likely. It is a hot mess. ;) Honestly, the problem lies with my coworker. He keeps changing shit on his end. It's been frustrating. Just trying to make it as robust as I given the cowboy nature of this guy. The shared document description you mentioned sounds like the way to go.

Comment: Maybe suggest you pair on each others code, so you can both feel each other's pain, and can discuss any required changes to the model as and when they occur?